# Want to change value of field, using a formula field, from Approval Process

Tags: apex, approval-process, formula-field

I have an Approval Process that has three stages, pending, ready, completed.

Based on what stage the Approval process is in, I want a field, probably a formula field that will display that value(pending, ready, or completed). How can I do this?

Is there an Api call on the current Approval status?

Answer (score 2):

Use a field update in the approval process step to set a value (Pending, Ready, Completed) in a custom field `approval_process_status__c` within the SObject that is undergoing the approval process.  Formula fields on an SObject don't have access to approval process status unless you set that status into a field in the SObject via a Field Update

It is unclear from your problem statement if your approval process has multiple approval steps.  Usually (and assuming only one approval step), in order to trigger the approval process, you would set the value via user entry/trigger/VF controller of `approval_process_status__c` to `Ready` and, upon save,  `approval_process_status__c` would be tested in the entry criteria of the approval process (if equal to `Ready`, then enter the Approval Process.

Here is an example (you may need to modify this to your specifics):

For SObject `Foo`, add custom field `Approval_Process_Status__c` type = Picklist with values = 'Not Ready', 'Pending', 'Ready', 'Completed', 'Rejected'

1. Your code decides record should be submitted to approval process; code sets `approval_process_status__c` to 'Ready'
2. Approval Process starts
3. Initial Submission actions - Includes a Field Update that sets `approval_process_status__c` to `Pending` (see SFDC doc on how to create Field Updates)
4. Some user approves the request
5. Final approval actions - setup another Field Update to set `approval_process_status__c` to `Completed`

If you have multiple steps in the approval process, you can create more status picklist values to track intermediate results in the process.  You should also use Field Updates within the rejected and recalled actions to set `approval_process_status__c` back to `Rejected` and `Not  Ready`, respectively.

Comment: Okay great. How do I set-up a field update that tracks the current approval process status?

Comment: updated answer to help

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using the standard approval functionality in Salesforce.

Basically, you want to use a custom picklist field to track approval status, and ideally, make it read-only for the users. Call it "Approval Status" (Approval_Status__c). The three picklist values are "Pending", "Ready", "Completed".

I am making assumptions on your process, but let us assume that:

"Pending" means not submitted for approval.
"Ready" means in the process of being approved (the approval process is active).
"Completed" means that the approval process is over.

You did not state what state the record should be in if the approval was rejected. I am assuming it goes back to "Pending". You could also have a "Rejected" status.

Given the above, this should work for you:

Have the Approval Status field default to "Pending" on creation of record.

The entry criteria for the approval is "Approval Status equals Pending". (Note that it should also include "Rejected" if you add that status).

Add a Field Update action when entering the approval to set Approval Status to "Ready".
Do your approval steps.

Have a field update in Final Approval actions to update Approval Status to "Completed"
Have a field update in Final Rejection actions to update Approval Status to "Pending" (or "Rejected").

Add Approval Status on page layouts as Read Only. No need for a formula field.